# ElasticSearch: How to apply regular expression on indices

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to restrict the return of a search query to only those indices that start with abc-* pattern.

I tried the following regex but it didn't work.

```
{  
  "sort": [
    {
      "timestamp": {
        "order": "desc",
        "unmapped_type": "boolean"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "regexp": {
                "index": "abc-*"
            }
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "timestamp": {
                   "gte": "now-24h"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }   
}
```

Is it possible to use the indices query and apply regex on it?
even the following doesn't filter appropriately:

```
{

  "sort": [
    {
      "timestamp": {
        "order": "desc",
        "unmapped_type": "boolean"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "indices" : {
            "query" : { "regexp" : { "index" : "abc-.*" } }
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "timestamp": {
                   "gte": "now-24h"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  } 

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a much easier solution simply by means of specifying your [index pattern in the URL directly](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-index.html):

```
POST /abc-*/_search
{  
  "sort": [
    {
      "timestamp": {
        "order": "desc",
        "unmapped_type": "boolean"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "timestamp": {
                   "gte": "now-24h"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but faced same problem in different case . I think problem with `-` in `"abc-*"` .

just replace - with space ,  it will work

```
"index": "abc *"
```

Answer (score 0):

The index pattern in the URL only supports native expressions, not regex expressions.  It does solve the problem though.

Comment: Can you please be more specific on how you solved it?